# Write string to file inside zip without creating file on disk. Java

Tags: java, zip

I need to read (Need todo other stuff) all txt files from zip "Inputs" archive, and save to other "Result" without unpacking files to disk, all need to do "on fly" in memmory.
Use ZipInputStream / ZipOutputStream for reading file.

The problem is write to result zip files. I try:

```
String zipEntryString = toStringZipEntry(zis);           // Read file to string
String parcedStringFile = parceContacts(zipEntryString); // Just return the same string at this moment nothing do

// Try write to string resultZip
InputStream is = new  ByteArrayInputStream(parcedStringFile.getBytes(ENCODING));
zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

int bufferSize;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
while ((bufferSize = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
   zos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

// Also try in whis way
// byte[] stringBytes = parcedStringFile.getBytes();
// zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
// zos.write(stringBytes);

is.close();
```

As I result create file with:

```
2b37 2028 3130 3129 2031 3131 2d32 3232
2d31 3120 2061 6263 4065 7274 2e63 6f6d
2c20 6465 6640 7364 662e 6f72 670d 0a2b
3120 2831 3032 2920 3132 3335 3332 2d32
... 
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

As I see to file writes bytes not string.

What Should I do wrong? what I miss?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Founded.

```
int ch;
while ((ch = is.read()) != 0) {
  zos.write(ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use In Memory File Systems libraries like [JIMFS(Java In Memory File System)](https://github.com/google/jimfs) which is developed by google and is one of the the best library of the kind.